# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it - when connecting to Azure DocumentDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cosmosdb

I have been developing a proof of concept application using ASP.Net MVC and .Net 4.5, connecting to DocumentDB on Microsoft Azure. 
Although, I am able to connect to my DocumentDB database through the unit tests to read and write data, I am not being able to do the same through my ASP.Net MVC application. I am consistently getting a message "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...". It is worth mentioning that this application is being run in a corporate network.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? It seems I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: I just checked the same solution at home (i.e., under different network conditions), and it seems to work just fine. Could it be due to firewall restrictions? Does the call to Azure happen in different contexts in the two situations - from an MSTest environment and from an MVC application?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Connection Policy, where you can choose between Gateway and Direct mode or the possibility to choose between TCP/HTTPS can affect your problem.

More information here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/20/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-1-2/